# Converting File to MultiPartFile with spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to convert File to multipartfile with spring. I have make this:

```
File in;
MultipartFile file =  null;
in = new File("C:...file on disk");
int size = (int) in.length();
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "application/vnd.ms-excel", false, nomefile, size ,in.getAbsoluteFile());
file = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

but receive this exception:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getSize(DiskFileItem.java:316)
```

i think that fileItem is null but on debug mode is populated, there is another solution?
I have this post [Converting File to MultiPartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648549/converting-file-to-multipartfile) but not work and not have solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting File to MultiPartFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648549/converting-file-to-multipartfile)

Answer (score 17):

```
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/input.txt");
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
            file.getName(), "text/plain", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

This is another way of getting multipart file from File object

Comment: I'd like to point out that MockMultipartFile is in **org.springframework.mock.web**.   And, this works nicely.

Comment: it only works in case of test environment only, otherwise it gives error

Comment: I saw the same issue Vipul did. Errors when trying to use in real business logic.

Answer (score 7):

```
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/validation.txt");
    DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/plain", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length() , file.getParentFile());
    fileItem.getOutputStream();
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

You need the

```
    fileItem.getOutputStream();
```

because it will throw NPE otherwise.