# Can't import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile outside of testing classes

Tags: java, arrays, spring

I'm trying to turn an image stored as a Blob in my DB into a MultipartFile to serve back to the client when it's requested. I retrieve the Blob as a byte[] and I'm trying to convert it into a MultipartFile to serve back to the client

I'm trying to do it this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25820543/7082628

But IntelliJ is telling me it can't find the MockMultipartFile part when I do the import of: `import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile`
 I can import this in a test class no problem, but not outside of the test class. Can I do it here?

Also, I tried to do this by implementing a class with my own version of MultipartFile as stated in another popular answer, but it's telling me it can't find a serialzer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't use that as that is for testing only. Just stream the `byte[]` directly to the client using an `OutputStream`.

Comment: @M. Deinum - how so? Could your flesh out an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your approach.

1. `Multipart` file is an HTTP `Request` format and not intended for `response`.
2. For a response all you have to do is write the file to the [response.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()). Which becomes way easier using `Spring`

Now coming to your original question that you can't import `MockMultipartFile`. That's most likely because you're using `Maven` and the dependency (most likely `spring-boot-starter-test`) has `scope` set to `test`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope><!-- CHANGE THIS TO "runtime" -->
</dependency>
```

But again as I  said before, there's no need to do that. You don't have to consider the `Multipart` when you're providing a response, it's a protocol to upload files.

Here's how you can provide a download link to a Blob in Spring

```
@GetMapping(path = "download")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws IOException {

    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(/* InputStream of blob */);

    long fileLength = /*Length of content, bytes.length or something */

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(fileLength)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .body(resource);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm doing it in this approach because the Image is one field of a DTO that contains a variety of fields that need to be served back to the client (like name, email, address, etc), and the image is one part of that DTO. I could make a new type of DTO, but it would have to store the image as a field, to be handled client-side. Any way I could change that approach?

Comment: ok, is the client browser based? If not then what are you using for the deserialization?

Comment: The requirements for this particular challenge do not state what the client needs to be. I'm assuming it's browser based, so I'm feeding a template the filled-out DTO in a @ResponseBody. Perhaps there's a different way?

Comment: If it's browser based client and you're planning to use JSON for serialization/deserialization, then you can't pass file object in DTO. As file object can not represented by `JSON`. One hack is to convert file object into `base64` String, which in your case would be ok to since you're returning Image. Base64 string can be directly used as `<img src="data:image/png;base64, base64_string....">`

Comment: As long as I don't have my image attempt in there, it does pass the fields as JSON back to the client though? But I will try this hack...

Comment: Doing it as the Base64 image is really the simplest way to go, I can add that to the DTO as a field and it's good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally the package i found which helped with
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding 'spring-test' dependency worked for me.
Thakn you.