# Java read file list from folder and convert to CommonsMultipartFile spring class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a folder 'C:\data' with a lot of PDF files and I want to convert those files to `CommonsMultipartFile` spring class.

In my project, I am using spring class `CommonsMultipartFile` in order to read file from the request and manipulate them. I prefer to reuse this project also for Files - java class.

I did:

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

and I want to convert to:
List of CommonsMultipartFile;

Thanks!!!

Comment: List of CommonsMultipartFiles? Here is an article on how to convert it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648549/converting-file-to-multipartfile

Comment: I read this answer before. I want to find a way to do it elegant for folder with more than 1000 files. those example do the conversion per file

Comment: In my understanding you have a wrong approach here. In your Controller, you receive CommonsMultipartFile, but you pass a File or an byteStream into your service. In that way you can create a second test/application, that uses the same service, but passes Files from the drive. You can commit the controller this way, as it is only a layer to transmit data to your service, it should not contain any reusable logic, only delegating data to other components.

Comment: I will explain the situation: I have a controller that contains files in the request and I parse it to list of CommonsMultipartFile. after I am using some utils function on the data that works on CommonsMultipartFile. I want to do the same process also for files from drive. this is the reason that I want to convert files to CommonsMultipartFile.

Comment: Why do you need CommonsMultipartFile instead of  MultipartFile? As for an elegant way streaming would do Arrays.stream(folder.listFiles()).map(this::mapToMultipartFile).forEach(this::processFile), when you are processing everything as a stream you will work with a single file at a time, so no matter how many you have, it will not matter.